# Error "Requested value 'UpdateDatabaseOperation' was not found" when attempting to generate an idempotent Code First Migration script

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, dotconnect

I'm using dotConnect 7.3.115.0 with EntityFramework 6.0.2.

When I try to generate a script for my migration, I get the error "Requested value 'UpdateDatabaseOperation' was not found."

Here are the details and stack trace:

```
PM> Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase -TargetMigration: Test -Verbose
```

Using StartUp project 'Domain.DataAccess'.
Using NuGet project 'Domain.DataAccess'.
Target database is: 'TestDatabase' (DataSource: localhost, Provider: Devart.Data.PostgreSql, Origin: Configuration).
Applying explicit migrations: [201403241857577_InitialCreate, 201403241941149_Test].
Applying explicit migration: 201403241857577_InitialCreate.
Applying explicit migration: 201403241941149_Test.

```
System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'UpdateDatabaseOperation' was not found.
   at System.Enum.EnumResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument)
   at System.Enum.TryParseEnum(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase, EnumResult& parseResult)
   at System.Enum.Parse(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at Devart.Common.Entity.Migrations.a.b(MigrationOperation A_0)
   at Devart.Common.Entity.Migrations.f.a(MigrationOperation A_0)
   at Devart.Common.Entity.Migrations.f.a(IEnumerable`1 A_0)
   at Devart.Common.Entity.Migrations.c.a(IEnumerable`1 A_0, String A_1)
   at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.Migrations.PgSqlEntityMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations, String providerManifestToken)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.GenerateStatements(IList`1 operations, String migrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.GenerateStatements(IList`1 operations, String migrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorScriptingDecorator.ScriptUpdate(String sourceMigration, String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScriptUpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScriptUpdate(String sourceMigration, String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Requested value 'UpdateDatabaseOperation' was not found.
```

---

### Update

It seems that the issue is related to generating the idempotent scripts using -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase

Per Microsoft:

> [Generating Idempotent Scripts (EF6 onwards)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#idempotent)
>
> Starting with EF6, if you specify –SourceMigration $InitialDatabase
>   then the generated script will be ‘idempotent’. Idempotent scripts can
>   upgrade a database currently at any version to the latest version (or
>   the specified version if you use –TargetMigration). The generated
>   script includes logic to check the __MigrationsHistory table and only
>   apply changes that haven't been previously applied.

I only encounter this error when using dotConnect pointed at a PostgreSQL database. Everything works as expected when using a SQLServer instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the report on this. We have reproduced this issue.

**UPDATE**

We have investigated the issue in more details and it is not related to dotConnect for PostgreSQL. The issue is related to the EF tool and the command being used in it:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration $InitialDatabase -TargetMigration: s -Verbose
```

It is necessary to use the '-Script' parameter or the '-Verbose' parameter, but not both at the same time.
Please try using, for example:

```
Update-Database -Script
```

To get detailed information for each command please use:

```
get-help Update-Database -detailed
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Including both the -Script and -Verbose flags doesn't appear to be the issue. I can run "Update-Database -Script -Verbose" and it runs fine. The issue appears to be generating the idempotent script using the "-SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase" parameters. Also, this all works fine when I use SQLServer as my database so I'm not sure this still isn't a dotConnect issue.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. We will investigate this issue in more details and inform you about the results as soon as any are available.

Comment: The UpdateDatabaseOperation operation in Code-First Migrations for EF 6.x is supported. New build of dotConnect for PostgreSQL 7.3.135 is available for download now.
It can be downloaded from http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/download.html (trial version) or from Registered Users' Area (for users with valid subscription only).
For more information, please refer to http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29346